# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'classobj'

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the coordinates from the intersection point of two lines and and at the intersect def I'm having this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'classobj'
```

What I can do to fix it?

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

class Line1:
    def __init__(self,a1,b1,c1):
        self.a1=a1
        self.b1=b1
        self.c1=c1
    def slope(self):
        try:
            return -self.a1/self.b1
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return None
    def isonline(self,Point):
        if (self.a1*Point.x+self.b1*Point.y+self.c1)==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class IntersectionPoint:
    def __init__(self,a2,b2,c2):
        self.a2=a2
        self.b2=b2
        self.c2=c2            
    def intersect(self,Line1): 
        xcord=(-Line1.a1/Line1.b1)+(self.a2/self.b2)-Line1.c1+self.c2
        ycord=(-Line1.a1/Line1.b1)*xcord-self.c2
        return 'True. The intersection point is: I' (xcord,ycord) 


coordinatesPoint=Point(1,1)
abcfromLine=Line1(2,-1 ,-3)
Line2=IntersectionPoint(3,-1 -1, Line1)
print abcfromLine.slope()
print abcfromLine.isonline(coordinatesPoint)
print Line2.intersect(abcfromLine)
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback, and double check the indentation in your post as formatted.

Comment: Why are you not getting an error on the `Line2=IntersectionPoint(3,-1 -1, Line1)` line? Your `IntersectionPoint()` class only takes 3 arguments.

Comment: I believe the correct form is `Line2=IntersectionPoint(3,-1, -1)` (In the original form, the second parameter for the object is -1 -1 which is actually -2)

Comment: I had it Line2=IntersectionPoint(3,-1 -1) but I was getting: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given) So I added the Line1 as the def intersect has Line1 as a second attribute

Comment: @user3399642 that was because you are missing a comma between -1 and -1. (In objects, every method automatically gets at least one argument- the `self`. If it says the method was given 3 arguments, it means that you wrote only 2 in the call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a *class object* to `IntersectionPoint()`:

```
Line2=IntersectionPoint(3,-1 -1, Line1)
```

`Line1` is a class. It's the third argument to the function, because you have no comma between the two `-1` arguments. As a result, you assigned `3` to `a2`, `-2` to `b2` and `Line1` to `c2`.

In the `intersect` method then, you then add that class object to an integer:

```
Line1.c1+self.c2
```

where `self.c2` is your `Line1` class.

You wanted:

```
Line2 = IntersectionPoint(3, -1, -1)
```

instead.

Next, you'll get an error on this line:

```
return 'True. The intersection point is: I' (xcord,ycord)
```

because that's like trying to use the string as a function. You are either missing a string formatting operation there or you are missing a comma:

```
return 'True. The intersection point is: (%d, %d)' % (xcord,ycord)
```

or

```
return 'True. The intersection point is: I', (xcord,ycord)
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Line2=IntersectionPoint(3,-1 -1, Line1)
```

to

```
Line2=IntersectionPoint(3,-1， -1)
```

you are passing in 4 arguments and missing a comma

Comment: your answer doesn't add anything to Martijn's, which was much earlier than yours.